# MacOS- Terminal login command with password in same line

Tags: terminal

when we execute following command

$ loging usrname

Password:

it prompts for the password to be entered in next line.

Is there any solution , so that we can enter the password in same line

Answer (score 0):

You can automate interactive sessions using a program like `expect` (see `man expect`; it's already installed on Mac OS X).